# SQL Server Count with case when

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below query to put skill values into the respective categories.

```
select distinct
case 
when skilldescript like 'cspace%' then 'CSPACE'
when skilldescript like 'gen%' then 'GENERAL'
when skilldescript like 'rope%' then 'ROPE'
when skilldescript like 'sct%' then 'SCT'
when skilldescript like 'trench%' then 'TRENCH'
end as Skill_Category
from skillTable
```

The query gives me the below result:

```
Skill_Category
--------------
CSPACE
GENERAL
ROPE
SCT
TRENCH
```

What I am now trying to accomplish is to have the query to return how many different skill sets fall under each category. So the result should be:

```
Skill_Category   Count
----------------------
CSPACE             11
GENERAL             5
ROPE               20
SCT                10
TRENCH              3
```

I tried using count() or sum(), but they are only selecting individual row count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group by the CASE expression and count:

```
select 
  case 
    when skilldescript like 'cspace%' then 'CSPACE'
    when skilldescript like 'gen%' then 'GENERAL'
    when skilldescript like 'rope%' then 'ROPE'
    when skilldescript like 'sct%' then 'SCT'
    when skilldescript like 'trench%' then 'TRENCH'
  end as Skill_Category,
  count(*) [Count]
from skillTable
group by case 
  when skilldescript like 'cspace%' then 'CSPACE'
  when skilldescript like 'gen%' then 'GENERAL'
  when skilldescript like 'rope%' then 'ROPE'
  when skilldescript like 'sct%' then 'SCT'
  when skilldescript like 'trench%' then 'TRENCH'
end
```

or:

```
select Skill_Category, count(*) [Count]
from (
  select 
    case 
      when skilldescript like 'cspace%' then 'CSPACE'
      when skilldescript like 'gen%' then 'GENERAL'
      when skilldescript like 'rope%' then 'ROPE'
      when skilldescript like 'sct%' then 'SCT'
      when skilldescript like 'trench%' then 'TRENCH'
    end as Skill_Category,
    count(*) [Count]
  from skillTable
) t
group by Skill_Category
```

Comment: `COUNT` is not a reserved keyword and you *don't* have to escape it as a column name.

Comment: I always do, in any case I have to use a word that *might* be reserved, though I mostly avoid them.

Comment: We used to too but recently undid it as excessive quoting uglifies the code unnecessary while does not make it any more future-proof -- they might add `Skill_Category` to reserved words one day.

Comment: *they might add Skill_Category to reserved words one day*, this is not that bad. Just think about `rank` in MySql, which was/is a very commonly used identifier. It was added in the reserved words in version 8.0

Comment: I would personally rather rename all `Rank` columns to `ItemRank` or whatever rank it is than quote any column in code.